# How can I tell if I am SSH'd in somwhere already?

Tags: linux, ssh, freebsd, hosts

Is there an easy way to tell if I am SSH'd in somewhere without typing 'exit'?

Like, if I am currently sitting at computer A and I SSH'd to computer B and then from B to computer C, is there a way I would be able to tell short of closing the session and using 'hostname' to discover where I am at?

(Presumably, this solution would also make it clear that I am not SSH'd anywhere, if I am just at localhost but if I am SSH'd elsewhere and from there SSH'd back to my local machine, I'd be able to tell.)

Comment: Related: [_Unix & Linux StackExchange: How can I detect if the shell is controlled from SSH?_](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9605/5769)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out $SSH_CONNECTION.  It tells you which IP and port you are currently connecting from and to.  At least, this is the case with OpenSSH.  YMMV with other servers.

Answer (score 11):

If you know you are 'ssh'ed, but don't know from where, try

```
w
```

at a command-line. The output includes a FROM field which may be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting your prompt to include the hostname; otherwise I like to use `screen` on every login with a status line containing the hostname (a bit complicated to [setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746/whats-in-your-bashrc/8469#8469), and it gets recursive with status lines within screens with status lines). You should be able to `echo $HOSTNAME` or just execute `hostname`.

Comment: Not as fun to set up but with the amount of machines I need to get to, I think it's time I just started using screen. :-).

Answer (score 1):

I like the "w" answer,

and another way is to check the hostname to find out what the computers name is:

```
hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, connect directly from A to C, if this is possible. This will avoid the double encryption. And perhaps will increase latency.

Also modify the shell variable **PS1** for every account to reflect the hostname, if it doesn't do it yet. This trick will also help you in situations when you use chroot.